# Delete a specific web page from history in Firefox Aurora for Android?

Tags: browser, privacy, firefox-for-android, delete, browser-history

Is there a way to delete a specific site visited from the browsing history without needing to clear it completely?

Comment: Do you also use Firefox for PC?

Comment: Yes, I do. And I use Firefox Sync

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only delete specific visited pages while going through the complete browser's history.

I asked because you can't actually delete any visit while they are filtered out by a search query. I think this should be allowed as a feature because if you had a big history you would need to spend an unimaginable amount of time to delete a very old entry while browsing it completely.

Answer (score 0):

The file `places.sqlite` stores history information. I suppose that if you manage to delete the entries you want from there and then sync your changes then these entries won't show up in your history. Here is some [info about editing this file](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Places.sqlite)

Comment: You can actually delete sites from the desktop without any hacks. But, I imagine that Android app will always have the visited site in its local database and re-sync it back to the desktop.